# Disable UpdateProgress for one UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am making some changes to an ASP.NET Web Forms application that has many UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress controls.

I have added an UpdatePanel and only for this UpdatePanel I want to stop all UpdateProgress from displaying when this UpdatePanel updates.

Many of the UpdateProgress controls do not have AssociatedUpdatePanelID set, so they display when I update my new UpdatePanel.

Is there a way of excluding an UpdatePanel from triggering an UpdateProgress without AssociatedUpdatePanelID set from displaying? Possibly some JavaScript?

I found some solutions here but they require that you know the ID of the UpdateProgress. There are so many UpdateProgress throughout this application I don't want to have to specify each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so with no answers I have investigated further and come up with a client-side solution.

This script will disable UpdateProgress controls from displaying if they do not have an associated UpdatePanel, and if the UpdatePanel that is triggering the partial postback has at least one UpdateProgress that is associated with it.

Long story short: if an UpdatePanel has an associated UpdateProgress control(s) then only they will display when it triggers a partial postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //array of original values
    var updateProgressDefaults = [];

    Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);

    function appl_init() {

        var c = Sys.Application.getComponents();
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (Object.getType(c[i]).getName() == "Sys.UI._UpdateProgress" && !c[i]._associatedUpdatePanelId) {
                updateProgressDefaults[c[i].get_id()] = c[i]._associatedUpdatePanelId;
            };
        }

        var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        pgRegMgr.add_initializeRequest(BeginHandler);
        pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(EndHandler);
    }

    function BeginHandler(sender, args) {
        //There is no _updatePanelsToUpdate if a trigger is outside of an UpdatePanel
        if (!args._updatePanelsToUpdate) return;

        //Check if the affected UpdatePanel has an associated UpdateProgress control
        var hasUpdateProgress = false;

        var c = Sys.Application.getComponents();
        for (var i = 0; i < args._updatePanelsToUpdate.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
                if (Object.getType(c[j]).getName() == "Sys.UI._UpdateProgress" && args._updatePanelsToUpdate[i].replace(/\$/g, "_") == c[j]._associatedUpdatePanelId) {
                    hasUpdateProgress = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (hasUpdateProgress) break;
        }

        //If the UpdatePanel has an associated UpdateProgress control then set all the UpdateProgress controls without associated UpdatePanels to a non-existant UpdatePanel
        if (hasUpdateProgress) {
            for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                var id = c[i].get_id();
                var type = Object.getType(c[i]).getName();
                if (type == "Sys.UI._UpdateProgress" && !c[i]._associatedUpdatePanelId) {
                    c[i]._associatedUpdatePanelId = "NullUpdateProgress";
                };

            }
        }
    }

    //Restores AssociatedUpdatePanelId for all UpdateProgress controls
    function EndHandler() {
        for (var key in updateProgressDefaults) {
            $get(key).control._associatedUpdatePanelId = updateProgressDefaults[key];
        }
    }
</script>
```

Source: [Disable common UpdateProgress controls for an UpdatePanel with an associated UpdateProgress](http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/827/disable-common-updateprogress-controls-for-an-updatepanel-with-an-associated-updateprogress/)